# preventDefault( ) on appended html does not work. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title is very much self explanatory. I'm appending HTML to my document in an AJAX call and I would like to prevent the default event when you click in an `<a>` tag generated by this function. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "/api/search/info/" +id,
accepts: 'application/json'
}).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
  $(".book-results #results").append("<a class='bookitem' href='b"+data.value+"'>Add Book</a>");
}, showErr);
```

Inside the same javascript file (but not within the AJAX function ), I have this listener:

```
$(".bookitem").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("HELLO");
});
```

When I trigger the ajax event, the `.book-results #results` gets populated, but when I click the `<a>` tag the default event gets triggered. Is there a way to make the listener work? If so, how?

Comment: It is not `preventDefault()` that is not working, but the `click` handler itself. It is because of the way you've used to bind the click event. The binding will not be applied to newly added elements. You should use `on('click', '.bookitem', function() { });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply an event listener before the element you are trying to attach the listener to exists. So `$(".bookitem").click(function(event) {...});` will only bind elements with the class of `bookitem` that exist at the time.

If you are dynamically adding elements, you need to either attach event handlers to those elements after you create them or, better, use delegation.

For delegation you attach the event handler to a parent element, for example:

```
$(".book-results #results").on("click",".bookitem", function(event) {
    // your handler goes here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery version 1.7 or higher use `.on()`...

```
$(document).on("click", ".bookitem", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("HELLO");
});
```

else use `.delegate()`...

```
$(body).delegate(".bookitem", "click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("HELLO");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".book-results").on('click','a',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("HELLO");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach event after creating element...

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "/api/search/info/" +id,
   accepts: 'application/json'
}).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
    $(".book-results #results").append("<a class='bookitem' href='b"+data.value+"'>Add Book</a>");
    $(".bookitem").click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log("HELLO");
    });
}, showErr);
```

Comment: Fine if you only have one AJAX call creating the dynamic elements. Otherwise you'll end up adding multiple handlers to that same elements.